# Is multi channel transceiver capable of receiving simultaneously from multiple transmitters?

Tags: component-selection

We are in the process of designing a system that requires transmission of data from a sensor nodes to receiver at processing node.Later on,the receiver node can send(transmit) certain commands/instructions to the sensor node.There will be multiple(say up to 60) sensor nodes at a time,simultaneously transmitting data to the receiver.Each transmitter will be assigned a specific channel and the receiver will identify the source of the data.The receiver node could be moving at some speed and signals could be Dopplerised. We need to achieve a range of about 15 kms,line of sight in 100% humid atmosphere.Antenna for transmitter will be a simple wire and Omni-directional. There will not be any gain at the antennae antenna.

·         Frequency Range : 160 Mhz to 175 Mhz
·         No. of channels:      60 for the receiver
·         No of channels for Tx : One
·         Data rate:  minimum-225 kbps

Is there any RF multi channel transceiver which is capable of receiving simultaneously from upto 60 transmitters?

Comment: I am afraid you have a basic problem. 15MHz over 60 channels gives some 25kHz channel spacing/bandwidrh which I believe far from achieving 225 kbps rate you are after. Anyway you'd indeed need 60 different separate receivers to get 60 different simultaneous transmissions. I'd rather go for a different approach: TDM over one single wide band channel

Comment: @carloc For TDM a multiplexer/demultiplexer is required.You mean to say that using a multiplexer at receiving end and after that demultiplexing the same.

Answer (score 0):

A Rf multichannel transceivers ? I believe they are called cell phone towers. Probably a similar approach might work. If you have 2 or more transceivers linked in a cellular configuration with overlapping coverage area will give you the 15km range.

I believe digital modes are less susceptible to Doppler affects
than their analog predecessors. You may have signal absorption  issues with VHF frequencies with 100 percent humidity . Other issues have to be considered as well such as terrain and vegetation in the path of the signal.

Digital modes require a good signal strength to avoid data loss.  If you are using simply a wire antenna with nonexistent  gain then you need a miracle.